# Prevent textview from being pushed further to the right - Android

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

UPDATE

The problem has been solved. It seems like I need both the:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

and:

```
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Image"
```

lines in the linearlayout.

```
   <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/Text"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingLeft="10dip"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Image"
  android:gravity="left">
```

I am trying to create a layout where on the left hand side there are two textViews, and on the right there is an image:

All is working fine except from when either of the textViews has a small amount of text in it.
When a textView has a smaller amount of text in it, it gets pushed further over to the right, and is no longer flush with the left hand side of the screen.

My question is, how to I make it so that no matter what, each of the textViews will always be flush with the left hand side of the parent; as opposed to it being pushed to the right if it has a smaller amount of text in.

I have included links below to images of the layout (I can't post images yet)

This first screen shot is of the layout working fine, and how I want it to look all the way through.

http://pbrd.co/1tZhJti

This second screenshot is of the layout braking. Can you see the highlighted row and how it is being pushed to the right, that is what I want to rectify.

http://pbrd.co/1tZhVss

Here is the code, if anyone can help me that would be great! Thanks!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/Image"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:src="@drawable/icon"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/Text"
      android:orientation="vertical"

      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="10dip"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Image"
      >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF7F3300"
        android:paddingLeft="0dip"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:paddingLeft="0dip"
        android:textColor="#FF267F00"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        />

  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` in your Linear layout...works like a charm

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/Text"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="10dip"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Image"
      >
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Yes this has solved it. It's strange because I need both the toLeftOf and the alignParentLeft lines. Thanks anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:weightsum="5"
      android:padding="8dp">

      <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/Text"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="4"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:paddingLeft="10dip">

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF7F3300"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#FF267F00"/>

      </LinearLayout>

      <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/Image"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/icon"
           android:scaleType="center"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I have done this before, but the problem with that is that the text now overlaps the image on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Image"
```

There is no need of that. Since you are aligning your LinearLayout to the left of your image, so when the text is small, the LinearLayout align itself to the right(to the left of image). so If you remove above line, your LinearLayout along with TextView's will now automatically alligned to left. But in this case you have to set ems to both TextView's to avoid overlapping with the image.

Comment: In your xml, inside your TextView widget, use this attribute

    android:ems=some value(for eg. 8);
For more details see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ems

Comment: Hey, I have now fixed the problem (see the question for updates) :) Thanks for the help anyway!